# Is there a way to incrementing numbered keys in an object when only adding values to that object

Tags: javascript, function, object

How can I increment keys by 1 in an object every time a new item is passed into a function.
Have tried incrementing a count by 1 each time but not had any success

```
function addItem(item) {
  let obj = {}

  obj[key] = item
}
```

Should return `{1 : item, 2: item}` and so on

Thanks

Comment: _"Should return..."_ - Then why do you create a new `obj` every time you call `addItem()`?

Comment: This should really be an array and not an object with consecutive "numeric" keys.

Comment: an array is an object with consecutive numbers as key. `push` is the way to go.

Comment: How should it return anything with a new created local object and no return statement?

Answer (score 0):

You really want to be using an array for this and then [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) new items into it.

But if you really really want an object with numbered keys you could invoke a closure that keeps track of the count.

An array is the better option tho.

```js
function add(obj = {}) {
  let count = 1;
  return {
    add: function(item) {
      obj[count] = item;
      count++;
    },
    view: function () {
      console.log(obj);
    }
  }
}

const addItem = add();

addItem.add({ tricky: 'Bristol' });
addItem.add({ pob: 12 });
addItem.view();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an array which is basiclly an object with consecutive numbers acting as key.

If you wish to use an object, you can use count and the object outside of the function scope and increment the count in each object addition.

```js
let count = 1;
let obj = {}

function addItem(item) {
  obj[count++] = item
}

addItem({"name": "john"});
addItem({"pet": "dog"});
addItem({"age": "19"});

console.log(obj);
```